# How to cancel async task via web request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, signalr

Here is the scenario: On user login I start a task which is listening to IMAP idle for mail notifications and it has live connection with the client via signalr(kind of push notification). Now the problem is how do i cancel this task? i.e. user cancel push notification or log out..

EDIT: as per my understanding for example if 5 users logged on to the site there are 5 tasks running? so how do i cancel individual tasks.

Comment: can you pls clarify that `Task` processes are executing in Web Service or Windows Service or else ?

Comment: hi @HarshBaid task is running within an mvc app.

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronous worker must be modified to support cancellation

http://www.csharp-examples.net/cancel-asynchronous-method/

You could also use the background worker which is a bit less complicated
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx

A problem I have encountered when you send a cancel to an external source (DB, app) which has already started a job, if it does not support canceling, you may have to wait until it finishes.

EDIT: I've never done this with MVC but found a good article on 'Using a Cancellation Token' for an asycn process which takes a CancellationToken parameter in MVC4.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4
hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a task you have to create a cancellation token and pass to it. Since each user is associated with a task you can store the task and cancellation token in the user's session.

Now using the cancellation token stored in the user's session you can easily cancel the task when he logs out or push the cancel button.

See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx) for task cancellation.

Comment: thanks @Mark. I did thought about storing the token, but how do i store it when it is not serializable?

Comment: @Iternity Are you using out-of-proc session state? You didn't say that in the question

Comment: I'm using In-Proc session. not sure how it make difference. explain please.

Comment: @Iternity Did you try storing the cancellation token in session? I just tried successfully now.

Comment: @Iternity when you are using InProc session (default) you can store any items in session and that are not required to be serializable but if you go for out-of-proc options like SQL server then this will be a problem

Answer (score 0):

The process can kill himself with no activity from the user. 
The easiest way to exchange  variables in the other thread - a file. 
Suppose the client browser is still open, the javascript timer call Ajax requests, which writes on server the time stamp to a file. Your task also periodically reads the file, and when the timestamp is too old, the process kill himself. The value of the activity timeout you can set of your choice.